# Different Page size for Desktop and Mobile in SXA

Tags: sxa

I am using Search Results component for creating blog list using SXA. I want to load first 10 results in desktop/tablet and first 5 results in mobile device on page load. Also on click of load more, it should load next 10 results in desktop/tablet and next 5 results in mobile.

I can see Page size field on rendering parameters of Search Results component. But it will be same for all devices. Can someone suggest me solution on this.

Comment: How do you recognize what is your current device (desktop, mobile)? 
Do you have separate devices (Sitecore devices) for it or you take into account screen size (grid breakpoints)?

Comment: We want to do it based on screen size

Comment: You will have to manipulate with `p` and `e` hash parameters to set number of loaded results (5 or 10) and then modify offset as well. 
You don't need Page Size rendering on a page.
There is no OOTB solution for that so you will have to write custom code/modify existing scripts.
You can find description of these parameters here 
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/100/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-sxa-search-service.html